# How the solution for getting sum is being timeout?

Tags: java

I'm solving a pretty straight problem in *HackerRank (project Euler, question 1 )* that says to find out sum of all numbers below certain given number (n) which returns zero as reminder with diving by 3 or 5 . I wrote the solution as following,

```
public static int getSum(int n ){

    int sum  = 0;

    for (int j =0; j < n; j++){

        if ( j%3 == 0  || j%5 == 0 ){

            sum += j;
        }      
    }
    return sum; 
}
```

In 2 of the test cases, this solution is getting timeout.  How to improve the code ?

Comment: I just tried , Program seems working fine. I print    `System.out.println(getSum(20)); ` and getting result : 78

Comment: @HelpingHands - - I guess the problem is with performance :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar - Yes that exactly I was thinking.

Comment: Here is the problem and 2 test cases are not working: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001

Comment: if its a performance issue then try to think of a way to not iterate over every number.  for example can you make a set of multiples of 3s and a set of multiples of 5 then loop through those instead

Comment: @pwilmot - Well, you will have to generate that set for each TC

Comment: well you could memoize it for example

Comment: @pwilmot, Nope. Even that would take a lot of time. There's a better way.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't there be any other way to solve it?

If `n` is `10^6`, the loop runs `10^6` times.

Can we reduce this further?

Remember Arthematic Progression series?

`a, a + n, a + 2n, ....`

Is there any connection between this and the problem?

Yes, look at the 3 multiples or 5 multiples.

```
3, 3 + 3, 3 + 2 * 3....
```

What is the sum till nth term?

Use the same for the `5` mutiples.

I don't want to ruin the fun of solving Project Eulers problems by giving you the whole answer. I gave you a hint. Have fun!

---

*PS: There's a twist in this. Observe it carefully.*

Comment: Ah, *Project Euler* requires mathematicians who are programmers :P

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar **Project Euler** is the best way to brush up your math and programming skills. I recommend everyone to try them. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will get back to you soon.  I just don't know why I get -1 for posting this, It's a legit question I believe.

Comment: @MonicaHübner - Because this question should probably go on [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar please don't recommend Code Review before confirming that it's [on-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

Comment: See the help center link I provided. "Performance" in and of itself is not an automatic qualifier for Code Review.

Comment: @Phrancis - This isn't off topic either. If you are pointing at something specific which prevents this from being a question on that site, please let me know

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Phrancis is partially right. As of right now, the OP hasn't specified if this is actually working elsewhere, and not just HackerRank. If it *does* work elsewhere, and is just timing out on HackerRank, then it's a perfectly on-topic performance-related question for Code Review.

Comment: @EthanBierlein - The code works but it times out. Performance issue. Even if it didn't work for all cases, codereview is OK for corner case failures

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar you're aware you're talking to two prominent members of the Code Review community? They are *very* good judges of what is on and off topic on CR because we constantly have to educate people on this.

Comment: @DanPantry - Frankly I wasn't aware of that. Next, I am not showing disrespect here (apologies if I came out the wrong way). Was merely curious as to why this question can't get there?

Comment: @Uma Kanth, could you please have a look in my new solution ? It's still failing in 2 test cases, but, no performance issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a simple and easy way you can use lambdas to perform this task like below :

```
    int given_num = 8;
    int sum = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 3, 5, 7, 8, 2, 90, 7, 4, 8, 7)//list of numbers
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> x < given_num && (x % 3 == 0 | x % 5 == 0))//filter the numbers which accept the required criteria
            .mapToInt(x -> x).sum();
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: That's an interesting answer. Do you provided the solution by using Java 8 ?

Comment: Of course . Lambda expressions are introduced in Java 8.

Comment: I still need to learn how to use this feature. I think the answer is good, I'm not accepting because I'm mainly looking for solutions build with logic.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote another answer based on the arithmetic progression provided as following,

```
public static int getSum(int m ){

int sum  = 0;

int three_start = 3;
int three_last = 0;
int three_count = 0 ;


int five_start = 5 ;
int five_last = 0;
int five_count = 0 ;


int fifteen_start = 15 ;
int fifteen_last = 0;
int fifteen_count = 0 ;

int n  = m-1;
boolean a = false , b  =  false, c  =false ; 

System.out.println(" inserted number m  = "+ m );

while( n >= 0 ){


  if (n%3 == 0 && !a ){

    three_last = n;
    a = true; 
  }

  if (n%5 == 0 && !b ){

    five_last = n;
    b = true;
  }


  if (n%5 == 0 && n%3 == 0   && !c){

    fifteen_last = n;
    c = true;
  }

  if (a && b && c ){

    break;
  }

  n--;         
}

System.out.println( " " + three_start + "  "+ three_last );
System.out.println( " " + five_start + "  "+ five_last );
System.out.println( " " + fifteen_start + "  "+ fifteen_last );


if (three_last != 0){

  three_count = (( three_last -  three_start)/3) +1; 
  System.out.println( " three_count  = " + three_count );
}


if (five_last != 0 ){

  five_count = (( five_last - five_start)/5) +1; 
  System.out.println( " five_count  = " + five_count );
}

if ( fifteen_last != 0 ){

  fifteen_count = (( fifteen_last - fifteen_start)/15) +1; 
  System.out.println( " fifteen_count  = " + fifteen_count );
}


if ( three_count != 0 ){


    sum += three_count * ( three_start + three_last)/2; 
}


if ( five_count != 0 ){

  sum += five_count * ( five_start + five_last)/2; 
}


if ( fifteen_count != 0 ){

  sum -= fifteen_count * ( fifteen_start + fifteen_last)/2; 
}

    return sum; 
}
```

I see that this time it fails in 2 test cases in HackerRank and I'm trying to assume what those can be. Any suggestions ?

** no timed out, so, I assume the performance is improved this time.*

Comment: This shouldn't be posted as an answer. Should've been an edit. Also Hackerrank doesn't want anyother print statements except the answer. Like "fifteen_count "..etc